# Reindex from code dosn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, reindex

I am rewriting a product Url on save. For this Url I am making a redirect (add new row in enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect). With this I want that old Url  go to new Url.
It works just after reindex(on url_redirect). So i.m trying to do this in code and dosn.t work. Any idea why?

**OBSERVER:**

```
  public function generateUrl(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)


     { 
            $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->formatUrlKey($_productName);

            $_product->setData('save_rewrites_history', true);
            $_product->setUrlKey($url);
            $_product->setUrlPath($url);

            //redirect when changing url. need reindexing
            $redirect = Mage::getModel('enterprise_urlrewrite/redirect');
            $fromUrl = $_product->getOrigData('url_key');

            $redirect->loadByRequestPath($fromUrl.".html", 0);

            $redirect->setIdentifier($fromUrl.".html");
            $redirect->setTargetPath($url.".html");
            $redirect->setOptions('RP');
            $redirect->setStoreId(0);
            $redirect->setProductId($_product->getEntityId());
            $redirect->save();


        }

    }
```

**SHELL:**

```
     public function run()
    {
        $indexProcess = Mage::getSingleton('enterprise_index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('url_redirect');
        if ($indexProcess) {
            $indexProcess->reindexAll();
        }
        $indexProcess = Mage::getSingleton('enterprise_index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_url_product');
        if ($indexProcess) {
            $indexProcess->reindexAll();
        }
    }
```

**CONFIG:**

```
 <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <url_generate>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>catalog/observer</class>
                    <method>generateUrl</method>
                </url_generate>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
```

--this is in `<global>`

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: If I make  php indexer.php --reindex url_redirect from shell it redirects url ok.